# Reverb effect with scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signals, signal-processing

I'm using numpy and scipy, I want to add reverb effect to signal.

It is possible to make reverb with these libaries?

Any help (even if it's just a kick in the right direction) would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont see why this is downvoted. It is a legitimate question: What are the tools available in scipy/numpy for processing signal in a such way to add reverb?
Thankfully, someone gave a good answer :)

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly possible to do signal processing in **scipy**, specifically using **scipy.signal**. Check out [their documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) for a list of useful signal processing functions. You can create a simple convolution reverb using **scipy.signal.convolve** as long as you acquire the impulse response of the room/space you'd like to emulate.